# Text added with jquery not showing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Edit**

1) The following problem only occurs in chrome. (i edited the title)

2) I updated the fiddle again to illustrate the problem better and to show that when static text is used in the second span - it does get displayed (even in chrome.)

3) I need the limit the width of the dynamic text (so it can't have css display: inline)

4) The title and the name have separate styles (that's why I have 2 spans in the markup)

5) Inspect element shows me that the text is there.... but it is not displayed for some strange reason.

=============

I want to make a centered header with 2 text elements:

1) A title (static text) and

2) content (dynamic text)

I put an ellipsis on the content to ensure that it doesn't overflow the box.

My problem is that the dynamic content - which i set through jquery isn't showing up!

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UjnvW/12/)

What am i missing?

Here's the markup:

```
<header class="header">
    <span class="title">Hello</span>&nbsp;
    ‎“<span id="Name" class="ellipsis name"></span>”
‎‎</header>​
```

CSS

```
.ellipsis {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.header
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #952262;
    font: bold 24px arial;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.title
{
    font-weight: normal;
}
.name
{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 370px;
    vertical-align: top; /*for firefox*/
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Name').text('Dan');
})​
```

Comment: I updated the link with the framework. This is not working for me in chrome!

Comment: @Will and others who closed this: I don't think this question should be closed... it doesn't seem so unlikely to want to place an ellipsis on text which is dynamic. Also clearly you can see that only chrome has a problem with this. WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ekFpk/1/

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from the CSS for `.ellipsis` and add it in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Name').text('The could be a long piece of text so I need to use an ellipsis here to trim it incase it overflows the container');
   $('.ellipsis').css('overflow','hidden');
})​;​
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Tom, that did the trick... do you know why this fixes the problem?

Comment: Both of those are good questions, and I wish I knew the answers.

Answer (score 1):

change the value of `display` with `inline`

```
.name
{
    display: inline;
    max-width: 370px;
    vertical-align: top; /*for firefox*/
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/UjnvW/7/)

**Edit**

this works, but I do not know why only if assigns a starting value, without this does not work.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <span class="title">Hello</span>&nbsp;
    ‎“<span id="Name" class="ellipsis name"></span>”
‎‎</header>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<button id="emptytext">empty text</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="shorttext">short text</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="largetext">large text</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('#Name').text('-');

    $('#emptytext').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#Name').text('');
    });

    $('#shorttext').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#Name').text('Dan');
    });

    $('#largetext').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#Name').text('Recuerdo de constantinopla');
    });

});
​
```

CSS:

```
.ellipsis 
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.header
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #952262;
    font: bold 24px arial;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.title
{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.name
{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top; /*for firefox*/
}
​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/UjnvW/15/)
[ellipsis tutorial](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: I can't use this because I need to use ellipsis on this text. (I edited the question and the fiddle to explain this better)

Comment: @Daniel but the `ellipsis` option is in '.ellipsis' class.

Comment: both classes are defined on the same element... so i don't think the ellipsis will work

Comment: @Danield I do not know well the reason, but both the response of Tom Smilack like mine, do something, change the element twice `Name`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Change it to:</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Name').html('Dan');
})​
```

But using `text` does also work.

If you were testing only with jsFiddle, you need to make sure 'jQuery' is selected as the library for 'no wrap (head)', (other options works too, as you use the ready event to call the function.)

Check the updated fiddle:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/UjnvW/3/</strike>
New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/UjnvW/6/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me. Which browser are you using? I'm using chrome.

Comment: It's because of your CSS, its pretty horrible CSS, the jQuery is working but you are hiding the word Dan because of your nasty css

Comment: @BuddhiP the new fiddle doesn't work for me. Also, I updated the question (and the included fiddle) to explain myself a little better